# How to make x variable change randomly and loop (Python)

Tags: python

I am trying to make a simple program to count how many times x equals 10.
Here is the code

```
from random import randint
x = randint(0, 10)
score = 0

if x == 10:
    score += 1
    print(score)
    x == randint(0, 10)
elif x != 10:
    x = randint(0, 10)
```

I used while clause and every possible clause for loop but I don't know why it wont work.
Any help would be appreciated. 
I am still a beginner in python so please don't mock me for the bad code.

Comment: Show your try and explain what didn't work (as properly formatted text in the question).

Comment: Where's the loop?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. There are a number of problems with your code. For starters, you forgot to use a loop (such as while True:) Secondly, you don't need elif x != 10 - just use else: as x is either 10 or it isn't. Also, the seventh line should be an assignment (=) not a comparison (==).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a for loop if you know how many times you would like to loop.

```
from random import randint
x = randint(0, 10)
score = 0

for i in range(0,5): # This will loop 5 times
    if x == 10: # If x is 10, add 1 to score
        score += 1

    print(score)
    x = randint(0, 10)
```

You can also use a while loop to do this unlimited times or until a condition is met.

```
from random import randint
x = randint(0, 10)
score = 0
while True: # This will loop indefinitely or until you break
    x = randint(0, 10)
    if x == 10: # If x is 10, add 1 to score
        score += 1

    print(score)
```